# Comparing files line by line in awk with delimiter

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, join

file1:

```
abc|123|check
def|456|map
ijk|789|globe
lmn|101112|equator
```

file2:

```
abc|123|check
def|456|map
ijk|789|equator
lmn|101112|globe
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
ijk|789|equator
lmn|101112|globe
```

Current awk script:

`awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} NR==FNR{a[$3]=$3;next}!($3 in a)' file1 file2`

This does comparison based on array content. How to compare line by line and printing only that results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to print a line from file2 if the 3rd field is different to the corresponding entry in file1. If so, this should do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next}(a[$1,$2]!=$3)' file1  file2
```

Yours wasn't working because you were taking `$3` as the key for array `a` and `$3` is not unique (both `equator` and `globe` are present in both files).

I agree with @drewbenn that both `grep` and `join` are simpler for this particular case, but here's a Perl way of doing the same thing:

```
perl -laF'\|' -ne '($k{$F[0].",".$F[1]}||=$F[2]) eq $F[2]||print;' file1  file2
```

Comment: You should use `a[$1,$2]` in case you get unfortunately similar fields like `a|bc|d` and `ab|c|e`

Comment: @glennjackman good point, answer edited.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) (or `grep -f`) instead.  But if you *must* use awk:

```
echo | awk '{system("join -v 2 file1 file2")}'
```

which is just an awk front-end to `join -v 2 file1 file2`.  Similarly, of course, you can use `grep -v -f file1 file2`.

Comment: `join` is the tool for the job, but your `awk` solution is cheating.

Answer (score 5):

[`comm`](http://man.cx/comm) is the real tool for this job:

```
comm -13 file1 file2
```

```
ijk|789|equator
lmn|101112|globe
```

If the input files are not already sorted:

```
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```